Frobenius norm and spectral decomposition
I work in $\mathbb{R}^d$. I have two symmetric matrixes $M$ and $N$ that have the same orthonormal eigenvectors : $\varphi_1, \varphi_2, ..., \varphi_k$, but different eigenvalues.
The eigen values of $M$ are $\lambda_1, ... , \lambda_d$ The eigenvalues of $N$ are $\mu_1, \mu_2, ..., \mu_d$
I want to compute the Frobenius norm :
$$
||M - N||_F
$$
I write the spectral decomposition of those two matrixes :
$$
M = \sum_{i = 1}^d \lambda_i \varphi_i \varphi_i^T
$$
and :
$$
N = \sum_{i = 1}^d \delta_i \varphi_i \varphi_i^T
$$
Is the following equality true ?
$$
||M - N||_F^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^d (\lambda_i - \delta_i)^2 Tr( \varphi_i \varphi_i^T)
$$
Thanks in advance.

Note that $M-N$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_i-\delta_i$ with eigenvectors $\varphi_i$, so we might as well assume $N=0$. Note that $\operatorname{Tr}(\varphi_i\varphi_i^T)=1$ since $\varphi_i\varphi_i^T$ is an orthogonal projection onto a $1$-dimensional subspace. Since the Frobenius norm is invariant under orthogonal transformations, $\lVert M\rVert_F^2 = \sum_{i=1}^d\lambda_i^2$ as desired. Or directly, noting $M=\sum_{i=1}^d\lambda_i\varphi_i\varphi_i^T$:\begin{align*}
\lVert M\rVert_F^2 &= \operatorname{Tr}(M^TM)=\operatorname{Tr}\Big(\Big(\sum_{i=1}^d\lambda_i\varphi_i\varphi_i^T\Big)^T \Big(\sum_{j=1}^d\lambda_j\varphi_j\varphi_j^T\Big)\Big)\\
&=\operatorname{Tr}\Big(\sum_{i=1}^d\lambda_i^2\varphi_i\varphi_i^T\Big) = \sum_{i=1}^d\lambda_i^2\operatorname{Tr}(\varphi_i\varphi_i^T)=\sum_{i=1}^d\lambda_i^2
\end{align*}
In the third equality we use that the $\varphi_i$ are orthonormal.

Thanks for your answer.
